# Replace string on wanted position in twig

Tags: string, symfony, twig

I have some string which has multiple words and between them there is always ', ' but also on end

```
str = ['str1, str2, str3, ']
```

I need to do

`str|replace(...)`

but with condition to remove only last set of character

> ', '

**All this I need to do in twig not in Controller**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use trim:

```
{% set str = ['foo, bar, foobar, '] %}
{{ str[0]|trim(', ') }}
//Outputs 'foo, bar, foobar'
```